# Как понять пункт 6.10.2 Source file inclusion \ 5 стандарта C11

Tags: c

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять один из пунктов стандарта C11:

> **6.10.2 Source file inclusion**
>
> 5. The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences consisting of one or more nondigits or digits (6.4.2.1) followed by a period (.) and a single nondigit. The first character shall not be a digit. The implementation may ignore distinctions of alphabetical case and restrict the mapping to eight significant characters before the period.
>
> *ISO/IEC 9899:2011*

Правильно ли я понимаю, что:

1. Имя заголовочного файла не может начинаться с цифры;
2. После точки (.) может идти только один nondigit-символ (т. е. расширение заголовочного файла может состоять только из одного символа);
3. Реализация может игнорировать регистр (маленькие и большие буквы);
4. Реализация может принимать во внимание только первые восемь символов до точки (т. е. длина имени файла может быть ограничена восемью символами);

У меня возникли сомнения, потому что, по крайней мере, GCC 6.3.0 не соответствует первому и второму пунктам.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, требование состоит в том, чтобы для имён файлов, удовлетворяющих ограничениям, была поддержка. Для остальных имён компилятор имеет право по своей доброй воле тоже работать, но кроссплатформенный код не имеет права на это рассчитывать. Но всё же, дождёмся мнения специалистов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Требования 6.10.2 распространяются на обе формы директивы `#include` - на форму с `<>` (включение *заголовка*) и на форму с `""` (включение *исходного файла*).

В первом случае последовательность символов между `<>` является именем *заголовка*. Стандартный термин *заголовок* (*header*) никак не привязан к файловой системе и в общем случае не является файлом вообще (реализация *стандартных заголовков* через буквальные *файлы* в файловой системе - не более чем простейший популярный подход, один из возможных).

Раздел 6.10.2 просто описывает *минимальные* реализационные пределы, которые реализации обязаны поддерживать в отношении символьных последовательностей между `<>` и `""`. То есть требования 6.10.2 направлены в первую очередь на синтаксис и семантику конструкции `#include` и намеренно абстрагированы от свойств файловой системы настолько, насколько это возможно.

В то же время, несмотря на концептуально различную интерпретацию `<>` и `""` вариантов, разделения требований между ними не произведено: стандарт скорее всего просто признает тот факт, что в реальной жизни стандартные заголовки обычно реализуются как исходные файлы.

Реальные реализации, конечно, будут предоставлять вам значительно более широкую свободу в выборе имен файлов и ограничивать себя требованиями 6.10.2 нет никакого смысла. Но в именовании заголовков стандартной библиотеки язык будет вынужден строго придерживаться очерченного в 6.10.2 минимума. Однако если вы ориентируетесь на формально-педантичную, злостно-занудную портабельность своего кода, то да, требования 6.10.2 следует соблюдать и вам тоже в именовании своих заголовочных файлов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А не могли бы вы привести пример одного из других подходов к реализации стандартных заголовков? Единственное, что мне приходит в голову, — можно «запихнуть» их содержимое в исходный код компилятора... Используется ли где-нибудь подход, отличный от файлов  файловой системы?

Comment: @eanmos: Я навскидку не знаю таких реализаций. Но идея действительно заключается именно в этом: директива `#include <stdio.h>` должна работать так, *как будто* в единице трансляции появились все стандартные объявления из этого заголовка. Но каким образом это достигается - не оговаривается. Текст "заголовочного файла" может быть вшит в компилятор, или буквального текста как такового может *не быть вообще*. Т.е. это может расцениваться просто как чистая "вкл./выкл." директива.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо большое за ответ!